# Why doesn't half of my jQuery work in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I'm attempting to put together a webpage that will play videos and have a list of videos that can be played. I've got it working great in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but of course IE 8 is providing lots of headaches. The video player itself is a native HTML 5 video player with a flash Flowplayer fallback (pretty much exclusively for IE 8). The HTML for that looks like this:

```
<video controls width="640" height="360">
  <source id='mp4src' src="videos/foo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source id='webmsrc' src="videos/foo.mp4.webm" type="video/webm">
  <a href="videos/foo.mp4" style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;" id="player">
  </a>
</video>
```

The anchor tag is a sort of container for the Flowplayer and is done according to Flowplayer's documentaion.

Now the jQuery I've written should do the following:

- Grab two pseudo-attributes of each list item (which each contain a URL for the video) and make them into variables
- Delete the two source tags inside the video tag
- Empty the anchor tag inside the video tag
- create two new source tags with the variables created earlier as the src attributes
- Change the href attribute of the anchor tag to the variable
- Run the Flowplayer function in order to re-populate the anchor tags
- Reload the video

And here's the jQuery itself

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.playlists11 #playlist li').click(function(){
    var url1 = $(this).attr('url1');
    var url2 = $(this).attr('url2');
    $('.content video #mp4src').remove();
    $('.content video #webmsrc').remove();
    $('.content video a').empty();
    $('.content video').prepend("<source id='webmsrc' src='" + url2 + "' type='video/webm'>");
    $('.content video').prepend("<source id='mp4src' src='" + url1 + "' type='video/mp4'>");
    $('.content video #player').attr('href',url1);
    $f("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");
    $('.content video').load();
  });
});
```

Now this works like a charm in every browser but IE 8! SO someone please tell me, what's wrong with my code that is making it not work only in IE 8?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: For those wondering, [jQuery 2.0 removed support for IE 6/7/8](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/). Make sure you're using a version <2.0 or have the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Well, [IE8 doesn't support `<video>` elements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video). So, what are you expecting? Are you using the [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) so it can at least fall back to treating them as `<div>`s?

Comment: No, but I'm using flash Flowplayer as a fallback, and the Flowplayer runs just fine inside the video tags in IE 8.

Comment: Typo here with the `$f`? `$f("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");`

Comment: nah, that's Flowplayer's function for setting up the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I'm getting really good at answering my own questions. :P

The fix for this one was to change`$('.content video a').empty();` to `$('.content #player').empty();` and change `$('.content video #player').attr('href',url1);` to `$('.content #player').attr('href',url1);`. I guess IE 8 not only doesn't know how to implement the video tags, but also just ignores their existence completely...